# Location in a form differ location in a tabBox,How i can fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button and textBox1, they located in a tabPage.
I want every click on the button to create textBox2,3,4 etc',
located a little lower than the previous button.

How can I do that?

I've tried to create a textBox, but the location textBox1 differ with "Location" in it's properties for some reason.

Here's the code to create the text box:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox(); 
    textBox.Location = new Point(textBox1.Location.X, textBox1.Location.Y + 10); 
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(textBox); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll have to post a [mre].

Comment: What GUI framework are you working with?

Comment: Show the code that behaves the way you describe it maybe we understand it then. Hint. Pixel values of Location at design time might be different from Pixel values at runtime because of desktop zoom. Just using hardcoded numbers for the "replacing" at runtime may fail.

Comment: @Ralf             private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Location = new Point(textBox1.Location.X, textBox1.Location.Y + 10);
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(textBox);

        }

Comment: @ZoharPeled windows forms

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank for edit,i have bad Eng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main problems with this code.
First, you don't take into consideration the height of the previous textbox, which might lead to overlapping controls, as you can see in the attached image:

[image]

Second, you only reference textBox1 in your code, which means all your textboxes will be displayed in the same location.

Here's a fixed version of your code

```
private TextBox? lastCreatedTextbox;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // assign textBox1 if lastCreatedTextbox is null
    lastCreatedTextbox ??= textBox1;

    var textBox = new TextBox();
    {
        textBox.Location = new Point(lastCreatedTextbox.Location.X, lastCreatedTextbox.Location.Y + lastCreatedTextbox.Height + 10);
    };
    // don't forget to assign lastCreatedTextbox!
    lastCreatedTextbox = textBox;

    tabPage1.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Which will look like this:

[image]

Comment: yeeeah,it's happened,thankkkkkkks

Comment: but,how now can i remove a TextBox click on another button?Find last element in collection ?

Comment: @kamihby Yes, that could work